# Server 2008 R2 does not boot and won't restore

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, hardware, boot

A Server 2008R2 machine was found restarted, asking to insert a bootable disk.
I booted from a DVD and tried to restore from a backup image made a day before to a separate HDD (with repartitioning and reformatting). After the restore completed (I wasn't there to see any messages though) I was just where I started - it won't boot from HDD at all showing only a generic "boot failure" message from the BIOS, after it's gone through all the boot options (HDD, CD and so on)

I booted from DVD again and ran DiskPart which showed disks pretty much as expected. I activated the proper partition, then exited and:

- checked that d:\BootMgr exists (d: because c: is the image disk)
- ran BootRec /Fixmbr  (success)
- ran BootRec /Fixboot (no success - got "Element not found")
- ran BootRec /RebuildBCD (found my OS where it should have been, offered to add it to the BCD which I accepted.

Then I restarted to the same result. Any idea what to try next?

Comment: It would actually be helpful to know what's showing on screen when it boots and/or what messages are displayed on boot. As your question stands, there isn't much for us to go on.

Comment: What shows is only the generic "boot failure" message from the motherboard/BIOS - after it's gone through all of the boot options (HDD, CD, network and whatnot). Thanks for the question, I added this information to the question.

Comment: Do a repair while booting from the install media. Boot with dvd 2008r2, click next on the first screen, and on next screen click repair, in the command prompt type;  X:\sources\recovery> startrep.exe (where x is your dvd letter)

Comment: Startrep worked for a while, showed as root cause: "the partition table does not have a valid system partition" and apparently repair was "successful" but it still didn't boot from HDD (looks same as before)...

Comment: Maybe also this is significant: when I get to the repair program, it doesn't list my OS in the list of "systems to repair", so the only option I have is to run a restore from image (which i did once, but it looks as before). I can also start command prompt with Shift+F10 from there.

Comment: Not sure what happened now.. I unhooked the second sata drive (with image) and the machine booted normally. I shut it down and hooked the second drive back again to continue investigations and again it booted normally. If anybody had any guesses as to what is going on, would be lovely...